# TypeError: '<' not supported between instances of 'generator' and 'generator'

Tags: python, sorting

When I run this code that sorts a `list` of `(str,int)` `tuples`:

`list.sort(key = lambda x: (abs(s - x[1]), x[1], len(x[0]), (255 - ord(i) for i in x[0])))`

it returns the following error: `TypeError: '<' not supported between instances of 'generator' and 'generator'`

which I found that it is because of  `(255 - ord(i) for i in x[0])` that sorts the strings in reverse lexicographical order.

Can anyone enlighten me why I get this error?

Comment: can you post the data and expected output

Comment: @komatiraju032 data is like this `[('NICOLE', 30), ('LAUREN', 6), ('MILA', 24)]` and it's output must first sort the `int` by its nearness to an `int` `s`, then by ascending order of `int`, then by the length of the `str`, then finally by its reverse lexicographic order.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
fun = lambda x: (abs(s - x[1]), x[1], len(x[0]), [255 - ord(char) for char in x[0]]) 
y = sorted(lst, key = fun)
```

Comment: Why did it work by adding a bracket? Thank you btw.

Answer (score 1):

If you try `print(type((i for i in range(10))))`, you can see actually it is a generator. So the right way to do the same thing is convert it to tuple `tuple(i for i in range(10))` or use a list comprehensions `[i for i in range(10)]`

Edit:

OK I think now I understand what do you want to do. Actually, this is a complex logic, I don't suggest you to use a lambda expression. But if you really want to, please do it below:

```
sort(key=lambda x: (abs(s - x[1]), x[1], len(x[0]), tuple(255 - ord(i) for i in x[0])))
```

This means, you first construct a tuple of 3 items, then added your string after caculated.

Answer (score 1):

Using `ord` does not sort in lexicographic order. It closely resembles lexicographic order for some languages in some instances, but has many peculiarities. For starts, in English it sorts `B` before `a`. If you want actual lexicographic sorting you need to use `locale.strxfrm` in your key, with your locale properly set. `locale.setlocale(locale.LC_COLLATE, '')` is usually enough to make sure your locale is set correctly for sorting.

```
>>> sorted('aAbB')
['A', 'B', 'a', 'b']
>>> import locale
>>> import locale.setlocale(locale.LC_COLLATE, 'English_United Kingdom')
>>> sorted('aAbB', key=locale.strxfrm)
['a', 'A', 'b', 'B']
```

The standard sort for strings uses `ord` behind the scenes though, and if you just want to reverse that sort, then the easiest way is to negate the numerical parts of your key and set `reverse=True`. This also works if wanted to use true reversed lexicographic sorting with your key. eg.

```
s = 0
my_list = [('NICOLE', 30), ('LAUREN', 30), ('MILA', 30)]

def my_key(item):
    return -abs(s - item[1]), -item[1], -len(item[0]), item[0]

my_list.sort(key=my_key, reverse=True)
print(my_list)
```

gives

```
[('MILA', 30), ('NICOLE', 30), ('LAUREN', 30)]
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to pass a function that compares a single element in the list, in this case a tuple element of `(str, int)` so you can compare a single string item with another one:
I am not sure I have understood what you are trying to achieve with that code, maybe you can try this:

```
l = [(0, 'a'), (1, 'b'), (2, 'v')]
l.sort(key=lambda x: 255 - ord(x[1]))
# l now is [(2, 'v'), (1, 'b'), (0, 'a')]
```

but you can let Python do the thing for you:

```
l.sort(key=lambda x: x[1], reverse=True)
```

Comment: That solves the problem when the string has one character only. But what if it's a word?